# How can I refactor this sealed class for DiffUtil?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, refactoring

I don't know if it is a good way that implementing comparison in the each item, not in areItemsTheSame, areContentsTheSame.

But I am trying to do it.

```
sealed class StatusListData(val type: Int) {
    object SearchData : StatusListData(0)
    object TimeFilterData : StatusListData(1)
    data class CategoryFilterData(val categoryFilterList: List<CheckBoxFilter>) : StatusListData(2)
    data class PageTitleData(
        @StringRes val titleRes: Int,
        var currentItemCount: Int,
        var totalItemCount: Int,
        val showTotal: Boolean,
    ) : StatusListData(3)

    data class StatusData(
        val receptionKey: String,
        val name: String,
        val phoneNumber: String,
        val address: String,
        val addressOld: String,
        val amount: Int,
        val deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethodType,
        val deliveryMemo: String?,
        val startAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val estimatedEndAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val endAt: LocalDateTime?,
        var detailStatus: ReceptionUiType,
        val prescriptionId: String?,
        val prescriptionUrl: String,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val approvedAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val dispensedAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val deliveryAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val completedAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val canceledAt: LocalDateTime?,
        val failReason: String = "",
        var faxMode: Boolean = false,
        var isConfirmed: Boolean = false
    ) : StatusListData(4){

        @Deprecated("not used", ReplaceWith("isConfirmed = boolean"))
        fun markAsRead(boolean: Boolean){
            isConfirmed = boolean
        }
    }
}
```

```
class StatusListDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StatusListData>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: StatusListData, newItem: StatusListData): Boolean {
        val isSameType = oldItem.type == newItem.type
        if (!isSameType) return false

        return when (oldItem) {
            is StatusListData.SearchData, is StatusListData.TimeFilterData -> true
            is StatusListData.CategoryFilterData -> oldItem.categoryFilterList.map { it.nameRes } == (newItem as StatusListData.CategoryFilterData).categoryFilterList.map { it.nameRes }
            is StatusListData.PageTitleData -> oldItem.titleRes == (newItem as StatusListData.PageTitleData).titleRes
            is StatusListData.StatusData -> oldItem.receptionKey == (newItem as StatusListData.StatusData).receptionKey
        }
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: StatusListData, newItem: StatusListData): Boolean {
        val isSameType = oldItem.type == newItem.type
        if (!isSameType) return false

        return when (oldItem) {
            is StatusListData.SearchData, is StatusListData.TimeFilterData -> oldItem == newItem
            is StatusListData.CategoryFilterData -> oldItem.categoryFilterList.map { it.nameRes } == (newItem as StatusListData.CategoryFilterData).categoryFilterList.map { it.nameRes }
            is StatusListData.PageTitleData -> oldItem == (newItem as StatusListData.PageTitleData)
            is StatusListData.StatusData -> oldItem == (newItem as StatusListData.StatusData)
        }
    }

}
```

to something like

```
interface ListType{
    fun isSame(newItem: StatusListData): Boolean
}

sealed class StatusListData(val type: Int), ListType{
    object SearchData : StatusListData(0)
        override isSame(newItem: StatusListData): Boolean{
            // TODO:
        }
    }
    object TimeFilterData : StatusListData(1){
        override isSame(newItem: StatusListData): Boolean{
            // TODO:
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

And

```
class StatusListDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StatusListData>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: StatusListData, newItem: StatusListData): Boolean {
        val isSameType = oldItem.type == newItem.type
        if (!isSameType) return false
        return newItem.isTheSame(oldItem)
   }
```

Is it better? If yes, then How can I implement it?

What I saw in the replace condition using polymorphism is something like this

```
sealed class StatusListData(val type: Int){
    object SearchData : StatusListData(0), ListType
        override isSame(newItem: StatusListData): Boolean{
            // TODO:
        }
    }
    ...
```

So that, when I pass any of the class then it will pass. However, when it is sealed class and it inherits the interface, then,

```
fun pass(item: StatusListData)
```

this won't work with

```
pass(item as SearchData)
pass(item as CategoryFilterData)
...
```

then, I should

```
pass(item as StatusListData)
```

and then,

```
override fun pass(item: StatusListData){
    val mItem = item as SearchData
    // TODO: something
}


override fun pass(item: StatusListData){
    val mItem = item as CategoryFilterData
    // TODO: something
}
```

is this a good way?? Is there any better solution and should I leave it?

Comment: What do SearchData and TimeFilterData represent? Can there ever be more than one of either type in the list?

Comment: It's a type of list item. 1. SearchBar, 2. Time Filter(Checkbox) Section, 3. Category Filter(Checkbox) Section( filter by category ), 4. title name 5. Result Item Section. At the moment, maximum 5. but can be less or might change to some other section sometime in the future. @Tenfour04

Comment: I mean, can there be two SearchDatas in your list, for example?

Comment: StatusData can be many. Since it's the actual list item data. But other types only once used.